Problems with a constant in regression analysis in Excel
I am using regression analysis in excel for a dataset. If I take into account the constant, then I get terrible r-squared values, but the indicators of t-statistics and p-values indicate that it is not zero.

If I nevertheless specify that the constant is zero, then I get good r-squared values, while the RSS, ESS and TSS indicators grow. X1 and X2 are becoming more significant, but I'm worried that the standard error has grown.

Do I need to take into account the constant because in this case the r-square is larger and how to explain the growth of RSS, ESS and TSS?
Note: the analysis is performed for data expressed in natural logarithm.

This is answered here. Nevermind that the answer uses different software - the fundamental problem applies to Excel as well. Long story short: R squared loses its interpretation when you remove the intercept.

+1.  Following up on this I'd ask the OP, @Danil Molchanov what the intention was for his analysis.  Is he simply interested in understanding the relationship of certain independent variables to dependent variables or, is he perhaps more interested in using the results of his model purely to obtain the best predictions in the future with new data?  Depending on the purpose, there might be a better diagnostic to examine than R-squared.

I guess the second one, because I need to choose a model for the subsequent construction of a deterministic boundary of production capabilities.
